# Delphi Multithreading out side the main form thread

Tags: delphi

For example i create a timer & within that timer i change my label's caption +1 On every tick of the timer works just fine, but when clicking on the form, or moving the application it thread-locks for a second.

My question is creating a thread outside the main forms thread, would stop thread locks For visual & Non visual Component's within the newly created thread

```
var
I:Integer;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
I:=0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer(Sender: TObject); //<< Interval set to 1
begin
I:=I+1;
Label0.Caption:=I.ToString;
end;
```

Comment: You can't run code in the main thread during size/move modal loops.

Comment: I see, i'd assume anything within another thread would not thread lock with the main thread size/move modal loops?

Comment: I don't know what your real problem is but don't assume that multi-threading will solve your problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan message-based timers, like `TTimer`, are still fired and dispatched in system modal loops

Comment: @BitRT you can't update main UI controls from a worker thread, so anything the worker thread wants to update would have to be delegated back to the main thread. So using a worker thread won't solve this issue